# Forward to ExternalName with traefik in kubernetes as the documenation suggests

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

Following the [Official Guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#deploy-trfik-using-a-deployment-or-daemonset) I got to the section on[Forwarding to ExtternalNames](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#forwarding-to-externalnames).  Where it says:

> When specifying an ExternalName, Træfik will forward requests to the given host accordingly

which points to the docs from kubernetes [services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

Which led me to create a service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

Of which Traefik happily ignores when I point to it:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-service.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 4080
```

I have also tried as an endpoint.

```
---                                                                                                                                                                                           
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 4080
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.0.0.3
    ports:
      - port: 4080
```

Does anyone know how to get traefik to point to an externalname as the documentation suggests?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you missed at least one line in your Ingress object - `traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "false"`.

Also, you need to create an Ingress object in a same [Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) with your [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

So, your [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) should be like:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
  annotations:
    traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-service.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 4080
```

And service:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  ports:
  - name: app-port
    port: 4080
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

Comment: And while adding the 's' to annotation did get kubernetes to accept it, it does not appear to be associating the port '4080'

Comment: Yep, thanks for a remark about an 's'. Misstype:( I fixed it in an answer. What about associating... Yep, you can use just a port, without a name - '4080'.

Comment: yes on the port, in the traefik UI all the endpoints on the right have a port i.e. http://10.0.0.5:8080   except for the entry created with the above service and ingress, which looks like http://10.0.0.3   with no port :4080 attached.

Comment: I have never seen it's UI:) But based on its [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#between-trfik-and-other-ingress-controller-implementations) that configuration should be OK. Maybe something wrong with your version...

Comment: you know the webUI that shows you what endpoints are active, brought up by this https://github.com/containous/traefik/tree/master/examples/k8s/ui.yaml

Comment: Thanks, I know it exists, but I just don't use any UIs anywhere except if it is the only way to get information. That's why I cannot tell you info why that endpoint is different from others.

Comment: regardless of whether you use the UI to get the info, the endpoint is wrong and does not point to the correct port

Comment: Based on documentation - has to. But anyway I updated an example and now the port number there instead of its name.

Comment: annotation still must be changed to annotations, and I just tested this again.  If you are not verifying with the UI how are you determining this is indeed working?

Comment: I'm calling this a bug.  I've added a github issue on this.  In which, I've posted a method for testing this where you can ignore the UI and still prove prove that this does not work.